# Convert KeyEvent DPad

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, keycode

I have a `RecyclerView` that is placed vertically. When an item inside the `RecyclerView` is focused, I can press the Left DPad button or the Up button to move the focus to the previous item, which moves the focus upwards on account of the `RecyclerView` being vertical. The problem is when I use the Left button, the focus goes to an element that is on the left (obviously). I want the two buttons to do the same thing when I'm in that `RecyclerView`. I thought of intercepting the Key event so `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT` becomes `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP` to solve the problem, but something goes wrong. Here's my code inside the Adapter Class:
(the comments are the attempts I made)

```java
public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    item_of_rw = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_of_rw);

    item_of_rw.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT && otherControl) {
                KeyEvent convertedEvent = new KeyEvent(event.getAction(), KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP);
                v.dispatchKeyEvent(convertedEvent);
                // v.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, convertedEvent);
                // v.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP));
                // item_of_rw.dispatchKeyEvent(convertedEvent);
                // v.setNextFocusLeftId(v.getNextFocusUpId());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```